# Regex for a string of n characters

Tags: .net, regex

I want to use .NET's Regex.IsMatch function to determine if a string is 8 characters long and matches the expression `AK-\d\d\d\d[fF]`.  So, `AK-9442F` would match but not `AK-9442F2` nor `AK-9442`.  How would I construct the expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the static [Regex.IsMatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdx2bds0.aspx), you can do:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(myTestString, @"^AK-\d{4}[fF]$")) {
  // passed
}
```

Should work for your purpose. Broken down, it's:

```
^       # must match beginning of the string
  AK-     # string literal, "AK-"
  \d{4}   # \d is digit, {4} means must be repeated 4 times
  [fF]    # either upper or lowercase F
$       # must match end of string
```

[GSkinner Test](http://regexr.com?2u4aa)

Comment: Thanks for the concise, yet detailed answer.

Answer (score 4):

Use this pattern: `^AK-\d{4}[Ff]$`

The `^` matches the beginning of the string, and `$` matches the end of the string. This ensures that the entire string must match and avoids any partial matches. The `\d{4}` matches exactly 4 digits.

```
string pattern = @"^AK-\d{4}[Ff]$";
bool result = Regex.IsMatch("AK-1234F", pattern);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  Yours was as good as Brad's below.

Answer (score 3):

```
 Regex.IsMatch(myString, @"^AK-\d{4}[fF]$")
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer!

Answer (score 0):

You alread have it.

Something like this should work:

`^AK-[0-9]{4}[Ff]$`

Comment: Needs the end of string anchor as well otherwise AK-9442F2 will match.